# How to run the Command from nest-commander in CLI?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest-commander

I have a **nestJS** application and added a **CLI command** using `nest-commander` according to their official docs:

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander

My directory looks like this:

```
+ src
   + command
      + test.command.js
   - app.controller.spec.ts
   - app.controller.ts
   - app.module.ts
   - app.service.ts
   - main.ts
+ test
```

To launch the web-application, I usually execute
`yarn start:dev`

But how can I start the command provided by nest-commander? It seems that official docs and even those of the github repository don't tell anything about it.

I need something like

`yarn run test-command`

or something like that. How to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As is written in the docs](https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev/en/execution/) generally you should build the application (`yarn build` should call `nest build` which should output the `dist`) and then you should be able to call `node dist/path/to/main-cli` where `main-cli` is the file in which you use the `CommandFactory.run()` method.

You could set up a `package.json` script like `"test-command": "nest build && node dist/path/to/main-cli"` so you can run `yarn test-command` and it'll run all the steps for you.

The above all also assumes you do not have ts files outside of the `src` that get compiled as well. If so, then your `dist` path would be `dist/src/path/to/main-cli`, so keep that in mind.

The last option would be to use `ts-node` and call `ts-node src/path/to/main-cli`, compiling the TS at runtime in memory.

Comment: "As is written in the docs" link is broken

Comment: Whoops. Changed my docs a few weeks ago